# Select2 box with asp.net on a hidden field - use HiddenField or input type=hidden

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

I have converted ASP.NET WebForms `DropDownList` to dynamic loading with the great [Select2 library](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). When I use loading of remote data, I need to use a

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" />
```

that I'll turn into Select2 box with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#foo").select2(...);
});
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to incorporate this into ASP.NET page and set the initial value from a query parameter, I can either use

```
<input type='hidden' id='foo' value='<%=Request["@id"] %>' class='bigdrop'/>
```

which I don't like, because I'll have logic in my markup, or

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="foo" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

and set the value in codebehind, but I am **unable** to set the class for the input.

Which approach should I use?

Comment: What do you mean with "I am unable to set the class for the input"? You are not talking about CssClass="SomeStyle" is it?

Comment: indeed I am, I totally forgot about the CssClass property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no CssClass property on HiddenField! But I solved it in jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function () {$("#foo").addClass('myclass'); }
```

Answer by "Axarydax"

Comment: there is no CssClass property on HiddenField! But I solved it in jQuery - `$(document).ready(function () {$("#foo").addClass('myclass'); }`